# l2tp/ipsec client-vpn docker on macos cannot connect vpn-server,note:"we require IKEv1 peer to have ID 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', but peer declares '%any'"

Tags: macos, l2tp

```
    ipsec.conf
    version  2.0
    config setup

    conn L2TP-PSK
    authby=secret
    pfs=no
    auto=add
    rekey=no
    left=%defaultroute
    type=transport
    leftprotoport=17/1701
    rightprotoport=17/1701
    dpddelay=15
    dpdtimeout=30
    dpdaction=clear
    ike=3des-sha1;modp1024
    # set this to the ip address of your vpn server:
    right=$VPN_SERVER_IPV4][1]
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3h1m.jpg What should I do to solve the problem?